# finds rows where 2 dates fields are more than 2 weekdays apart

Tags: mysql, cakephp, date

I need to fetch the number of rows from a table where one date field is within 2 week days of another date field. How would I do this in CakePHP?

This is what I have so far:

```
$this->Task->find('count', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Task.created >= Task.status_update'
    )
))
```

What I really want to do is to compare `Task.created` to `(Task.status_update - 2 weekdays)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for something like this:

```
$this->Task->find('count', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Task.created >= DATE_SUB( Task.status_update , INTERVAL 2 DAY )'
    )
))
```

Havent tested this code but I based it on this:

`select date_sub(curdate(),interval 2 day)as Date;` which return the date minus two days.

HTH

Comment: Thanks, but I really need it to specifically only take working days into account - do you know if there would be a way to modify this accordingly?